# how to join tables with generalization

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having trouble performing a JOIN on tables the problem is this:

In a report cart system I have users, such as students, parents and school employees. I need to generate an SQL statement that when I enter the access ID of the parents it lists all students related to parents ID

Follow the Model:

[image: Model]

Is this the best way to implement this "Generalization" and this relationship between parents and students, since they are all users? Can someone help me?

SQL code:

```
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `testeboletim`.`type_user`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`type_user` (
          `idtype_user` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `role` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idtype_user`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB;


        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `testeboletim`.`user`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`user` (
          `iduser` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
          `birth` DATE NULL,
          `telephone` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
          `phone` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
          `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `type_user_idtype_user` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`, `type_user_idtype_user`),
          INDEX `fk_usuario_tipo_usuario_idx` (`type_user_idtype_user` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_tipo_usuario`
            FOREIGN KEY (`type_user_idtype_user`)
            REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`type_user` (`idtype_user`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB;


        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `testeboletim`.`student`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`student` (
          `idstudent` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `user_iduser` INT NOT NULL,
          `user_type_user_idtype_user` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idstudent`, `user_iduser`, `user_type_user_idtype_user`),
          INDEX `fk_aluno_usuario1_idx` (`user_iduser` ASC, `user_type_user_idtype_user` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_usuario1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`user_iduser` , `user_type_user_idtype_user`)
            REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`user` (`iduser` , `type_user_idtype_user`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB;


        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `testeboletim`.`parents`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`parents` (
          `idparents` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `user_iduser` INT NOT NULL,
          `user_type_user_idtype_user` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idparents`, `user_iduser`, `user_type_user_idtype_user`),
          INDEX `fk_responsavel_usuario1_idx` (`user_iduser` ASC, `user_type_user_idtype_user` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_responsavel_usuario1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`user_iduser` , `user_type_user_idtype_user`)
            REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`user` (`iduser` , `type_user_idtype_user`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB;


        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `testeboletim`.`student_has_parents`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`student_has_parents` (
          `student_idstudent` INT NOT NULL,
          `student_user_iduser` INT NOT NULL,
          `parents_idparents` INT NOT NULL,
          `parents_user_iduser` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`student_idstudent`, `student_user_iduser`, `parents_idparents`, `parents_user_iduser`),
          INDEX `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_responsavel1_idx` (`parents_idparents` ASC, `parents_user_iduser` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_aluno1_idx` (`student_idstudent` ASC, `student_user_iduser` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_aluno1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`student_idstudent` , `student_user_iduser`)
            REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`student` (`idstudent` , `user_iduser`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_responsavel1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`parents_idparents` , `parents_user_iduser`)
            REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`parents` (`idparents` , `user_iduser`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB;


        SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
        SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
        SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: There shouldn't really be a need for the separate `parents` and `student` table if there is something in the `user` table that distinguishes them (perhaps `type_user` already does?). In that situation, each `student_has_parents` would simply have two separate references to `user`. The only downside of the approach I suggest is that it isn't very simple purely in MySQL to make sure a `user` won't end up on an inappropriate side of the relationship; but you would have similar issues keeping inappropriate users out the tables I suggest eliminating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, we would need to look at `testeboletim`.`student`, `testeboletim`.`parents`, and either `testeboletim`.`student_has_parents` or `testeboletim`.`user`. I have decided to solve your problem using `testeboletim`.`user`, because it was clearer in terms of refrence keys, and what not.

**Solution using `testeboletim`.`user`**

Based on your question, we are looking for all rows in `testeboletim`.`student`, that have a corresponding `iduser` `testeboletim`.`user` based on the `user_iduser` of `testeboletim`.`parents`.

-- SQL Definition:

```
SELECT * FROM `testeboletim`.`student` WHERE `user_iduser` IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(`iduser`) FROM `testeboletim`.`user` WHERE `iduser` IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT(`user_iduser`) FROM `testeboletim`.`parents`)
        );
```

Now to do the same thing with `JOIN`, would require the use of `LEFT JOIN`; in this case `testeboletim`.`student`.

```
SELECT * FROM `testeboletim`.`student` AS `student`
LEFT JOIN `testeboletim`.`user` AS `user` 
ON `student`.`user_iduser` = `user`.`iduser`
LEFT JOIN `testeboletim`.`parents` AS `parents`
ON `user`.`iduser` = `parents`.`user_iduser`;
```

Since I don't have any values, I'm going to share with you the explanation, in order to "prove" that the query works.

```
mysql>  SELECT * FROM `testeboletim`.`student` AS `student`
    ->     LEFT JOIN `testeboletim`.`user` AS `user` 
    ->     ON `student`.`user_iduser` = `user`.`iduser`
    ->     LEFT JOIN `testeboletim`.`parents` AS `parents`
    ->     ON `user`.`iduser` = `parents`.`user_iduser`;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN  SELECT * FROM `testeboletim`.`student` AS `student`
    ->     LEFT JOIN `testeboletim`.`user` AS `user` 
    ->     ON `student`.`user_iduser` = `user`.`iduser`
    ->     LEFT JOIN `testeboletim`.`parents` AS `parents`
    ->     ON `user`.`iduser` = `parents`.`user_iduser`;
+------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys               | key                         | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                           |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | student | index | NULL                        | PRIMARY                     | 12      | NULL                     |    1 | Using index                                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | user    | ALL   | PRIMARY                     | NULL                        | NULL    | NULL                     |    1 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | parents | ref   | fk_responsavel_usuario1_idx | fk_responsavel_usuario1_idx | 4       | testeboletim.user.iduser |    1 | Using where; Using index                        |
+------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```